# iptables blocking ability to ping/reach domain names

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, firewall, ping

I'm trying to set up some firewall rules for allowing SSH, incoming ping, munin, and MySQL between one server and another (all those services are working fine with my rules), but when I apply the rules, I can no longer ping or resolve any DNS (so I can ping `74.125.225.65` but not `google.com`).

Here are the rules I'm using:

```
# Accept traffic on localhost:
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow SSH from anywhere:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Accept ICMP Ping requests (incoming and outgoing):
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT

# Allow munin from subdomain.example.com:
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 123.23.45.1 --dport 4949 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 123.23.45.1 --dport 4949 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow MySQL from subdomain.example.com:
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp -s 123.23.45.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 123.23.45.1 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

# Drop all other traffic:
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

`resolv.conf`, `/etc/hosts`, etc. are all correct, and if I simply do a `$ iptables -F`, and ping google again, it works fine. Only after the firewall rules are applied do I get `ping: unknown host google.com`.

Comment: What is the current state of your firewall? And why are you using these strange OUTPUT rules?

Comment: I don't have a drop rule after the output chain yet, but I also want to make sure that only certain things can leave the server as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no rules to allow DNS traffic, so how could it work?

Comment: `<facepalm>` iptables -I INPUT -p udp -i eth0 --sport 53 -j ACCEPT `</facepalm>`

Comment: Although it will probably work even if you don't, the standards say you need to allow outbound TCP connections to port 53 too (and, of course, the reply packets). A DNS reply can be too large to fit in a single UDP datagram.